# From mipmap to drawable

Tags: java, android

I used to have the images of my app in the mipmap folders but I didn't have deferent resolutions ( I had the exactly same image in all 5 folders). In order to save space I moved those images in the drawable folder (except the launcher icons that are the only images that have different resolutions) . But when I open an activity that has some of those images I get the following crash error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 
29304012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 
23MB until OOM
at 
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native 
Method)
at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native 
Method)
at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFac 
tory.java:624)
at  
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(Bi 
tmapFactory.java:457)
at 
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResource 
Stream(Drawable.java:1152)
at 
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromResourceSt 
ream(ResourcesImpl.java:1272)
at 
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCooki 
e(ResourcesImpl.java:743)
at 
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(Resourc 
esImpl.java:585)
at 
android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(Miui  
ResourcesImpl.java:308)
at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.ja  va:872)
at 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.ja 
va:930)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4182)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>. 
(AppCompatButton.java:70)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>. 
(AppCompatButton.java:66)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButt 
on(AppCompatViewInflater.java:186)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createVie 
w(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.create 
View(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCre 
ateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInfl 
ater.java:794)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInfl 
ater.java:752)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.j 
 ava:846)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppC
ompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at       
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(
AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at 
com.soon.coming.endturnbutton.themes.onCreate(themes.java:38)
at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityT hread.java:2808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThre  ad.java:1541)
at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.r 
un(ZygoteInit.java:883)
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue before, this was because i had a very very large image inside my drawable folder to be loaded (out of memory).

What i did, is to drag all my drawables to this [**site**](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) to generate Android assets and returned them back to my drawables with the new sizes (and resolutions as well like hdpi,....etc).

Answer (score 0):

This means you are out of memory. What you can do to save space is move the images back into the mipmap folder but you only need it in one of them. You do not need to put it in all five. It is not the best practice, but it would work.

Comment: if i have the images in only one mipmap folder they come out blury

Comment: Try moving it to a different mipmap folder. Maybe the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

use this link to create appropriate resolution images(hdp,xdp, xxdp) and then put these images in related drawable resource directory

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/